# Alternate of joining multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query where I need to Inner join more than 16 tables.
query is taking too much time for execution, I have also add index on various columns but still facing same problem.

Can any one suggest best alternative for this?

I have a kind of CMS where we have different type of information related to product
like category, category with product mapping, item type, type mapping, language, language mapping, etc...

my tables are fully normalize nothing is wrong with database schema design.

Comment: Are you aware of the idea of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization ?

Comment: Develop a new schema that doesn't require 16 joins? There is (most likely) no speedier alternative to JOINS. (In fact, JOINS are often used as a speedier replacement for EXISTS, NOT EXISTS, IN, NOT IN and subqueries). Unless you are going to share your schema, and what your are trying to do, everyone is guessing.

Comment: I doubt that JOINs are your problem.

Comment: Also, share the results of running the query with `EXPLAIN` in front of it, along with the schema details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database layout requires you to do 16 joins before you have the data you need, then the problem is not the join, but the database layout. Try rethinking the database, use the denormalization steps, but stop at a certain point. Depending on the use of your database, you shouldn't denormalize too far.
If reworking the database is not an option, then I would look into materialized views, or intermediary tables. Bring part of the data together in one new view or table, and use that table in your query. This table of course needs to be updated regularly, depending on the needed "freshness" of your data. In case you would use a view, the data is gathered at the time of the request, but this will come at an additional performance cost of course.

Comment: My tables are far demoralize, all the tables are divided in to small parts and mappings, and now fetching data need to join all those small parts and that is creating problem.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I mean by stopping in time :-) Depending on your need, you need to de normalize up to step 3 or 4. Step 5 is almost strictly theoretical. But alot depends on the use of your database and your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that JOINing on more than seven tables is not advisable.

I don't know anything about your schema, but I'd wonder if VIEWs might help you.

Comment: Can you provide references for your two statements - not joining more than 7 tables and how views can help? I have never seen the query optimizer process a complex query any differently than if I abstracted some of the JOINs as a view.

Answer (score 0):

I dont  think there is any alternative to JOINS. But depending on your requirement you can use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN in some situation.

You can also put the condtion of EXISTS and NOT EXISTS but this is all a guess without watching your schema

Comment: Are you saying a  `LEFT JOIN` will perform better than an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @AgRizzo:- NO I am saying that they will perform better I am just saying that OP can use LEFT JOINS also for some situation. Am I missing something?

Comment: The OP is looking for alternatives because their query is too slow.

Comment: @AgRizzo:- I dont think that there is any alternative of JOINS. However I suggested to use the LEFT JOINS as I thought it could help OP. But alternatives to JOIN's looks difficult to find ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should draw simple connections between tables and than start to build your query, first time maybe looks messy, but start by draw simple connections is good start